# Supervisor and directory option

Tags: python, celery

I was configuring supervisor daemon to be able to start/stop Celery.

It did not work. After debuging back and forth I realized that the problem was that it did not change the working directory to the one mentioned in the `directory` option in supervisord.conf under `program:celery` configuration.

Hopefully there is a `workdir` in Celery but I am curious - what is the purpose of the `directory` option then?

Answer (score 0):

Directory option in supervisord = where we mention our project directory path.
Example:
directory="/home/celery/pictures/myapp"

Comment: Don't quite understand what you are saying.